# Unable to run programs off of my external media

Tags: 14.04, sd-card

My drive is formatted to ext3/ext4, so I know it's not an issue with file-system executable permissions.

I had this problem with one program, so to test it out, I made a quick bash file that simply opened a terminal and ran `sudo apt-get update`. When running it, I get the following box:

["63 GB Volume" contains software intended to be automatically started. Would you like to run it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK7y4.png)

If I click `Run`, I then get another box:

[Oops! There was a problem running this software. Unable to locate the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRvP8.png)

Are there any solutions I can try (besides putting the software on my internal drive)? I'm trying to run programs off of the external drive specifically because my internal drive is low on space.

I've also checked that the "Allow running as executable" box is checked, and it is (in fact, I actually can't check it *off*.)

---

EDIT: Apologies for not including the script. This is what's in the file:

```
#! /bin/bash

gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "sudo apt-get update; exec bash"'
```

I am having this issue with all software I try to run on the external media.

Here is the output of `mount | grep /dev/sd`:

```
/dev/sda1 on /var/host/media/removable/SD Card type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,dirsync,user_id=302,group_id=302,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: Add your script code to your question. is that only contains `sudo apt-get update`? what if you run it from terminal? does it show you any error? (from terminal).

Comment: Running it from the terminal doesn't seem to give me any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drive is mounted with the `noexec` option. AFAIK This literally disallows executing programs on the volume regardless of the settings on the individual files. Specific solutions vary depending on how you mounted the volume in the first place, but from a general standpoint you need to either mount the volume without the `noexec` option or swap it explicitly for the `exec` option. Here's an excerpt from the fuse man page:

```
OPTIONS
       Most of the generic mount options described in mount are supported (ro,
       rw, suid, nosuid, dev,  nodev,  exec,  noexec,  atime,  noatime,  sync,
       async,  dirsync). Filesystems are mounted with nodev,nosuid by default,
       which can only be overridden by a privileged user.
```

And the relevant portion of the mount man page:

```
noexec Do  not  allow  direct  execution of any binaries on the mounted
              filesystem.  (Until recently it was  possible  to  run  binaries
              anyway  using a command like /lib/ld*.so /mnt/binary. This trick
              fails since Linux 2.4.25 / 2.6.0.)
```

As far as I know, fuse doesn't support the remount option so I believe you have to unmount `/dev/sda1` (after closing any open files on the device) with `fusermount -u "/var/host/media/removable/SD Card"` and then mount it again with the options you require (other than noexec) normally using the `mount` command. See `man mount` `man fuse` and `man fusermount` for further details as deemed necessary for your specific situation.

Comment: I tried the following: `sudo mount exec /dev/sda1 /media/seth`, however It didn't seem to work. It just gave me a list of mounting options.

EDIT: I forgot to add "-o" in between `mount` and `exec`. Whoops. Thanks to all of you for your help, programs run fine now! :D

Comment: the `mount` command uses a `-o` in front of the options as noted in the `man mount` page. That being the case you might try `sudo mount -o exec /dev/sda1 /media/seth` or simply `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/seth` as noexec isn't a default for ext3/ext4 file systems

Comment: I'm glad we got it sorted!